# Is "stepstone" a valid word?

Tags: abbreviations

Is "stepstone" a valid abbreviation of "stepping stone"?

Is this a good way to form abbreviations in English?

**Research done**

Searched some online dicts but they don't have the word "stepstone":

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/spellcheck/american_english/?q=stepstone

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=stepstone

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/spellcheck/english/?q=stepstone

Comment: ***Stepstone***: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Stepstone

Comment: They have 2 different meanings. Look in OALD and MW.

Comment: It might also work as a designation for something that is a stone only by marriage—as opposed to a birthstone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both *stepping stone* and *step stone* have definitions as concrete (no pun intended) objects -- the former as part of a pathway of stones, and the latter as a foundation before a door or stairway.  *Stepping stone* has the (much) more common use as an intermediate means toward accomplishing some end.  But consider the following from [*Pulpit Pungencies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BXUXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA99&dq=%22stepstone%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7wOyLguLLAhWIbSYKHR_rCmUQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=%22stepstone%22&f=false) (1866, quoting an 1859 sermon) by Henry Ward Beecher:

> And wine is **stepstone** to brandy. Beer is **stepstone** the other way. It does not lead up to brandy, but it leads down to drunk, and beastly drunk.

But this is not an example of an abbreviation in the sense of shortening a full length term to something that represents the longer version, e.g. the way *assoc.* is an abbreviation for *association*.  Beecher meant to use *stepstone* the same way we use the separate term *stepping stone*.  This is a very common occurrence, and it's why colleges have *quads*, which are spaces that form quadrilaterals.  In this case, HWB notwithstanding, *stepping stone* is so far the winner.